# CSS :focus automatically opens link on android device

Tags: android, html, ios, css

On a website I use `:hover` for web and `:focus` for touch device on a link. But on android devices if I touch the link it do the `:focus` but then automatically open the link.

It should do the `:focus` and if the user clicks again on the link, then it should open the link. Is this possible with pure CSS?

I got a short example of my `:hover` and `:focus` code:

```
#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu, #menu li:focus ul.sub-menu{
    display:block;
}
```

There is no problem on iOS (works perfectly on iOS). Just on android devices.

Comment: I dont think this is possible with CSS only. You will need some javascript

Comment: Okay, I used JavaScript before. Not often but sometimes I did. You got a solution for this? :)

Comment: Im pretty sure I can help you with that, but would you please update your question with the relevant HTML code? Thanks

Comment: Okay, thanks. You can visit the page here so you got the whole source code :) http://www.tvkaltenbach.ch/

Comment: Thats even better. And ouh, you're from Switzerland too?!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a bit of javascript (jQuery, which is already included in your site) and [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to determine if the user is on a touchscreen device. There are other methods to check for touch but Modernizr will get you the best results in my opinion.

So first include Modernizr. You can download it from their website or use a cdn like cdnjs.com

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

After that, add this javascript to your site:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(Modernizr.touch){
        $('#menu-mainmenu').on('click', '> li', function(e){
            if(!$(this).data('open')){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $(this).data('open', true);
        });
    }
});
```

So if you're on a touch device and click on a mainmenu-item then submenu pops up (due the `:focus` styling) but the link is blocked because of `e.preventDefault()`. Then the data-value "open" is set to true, so if the user taps on the link again, the if check fails and the link opens normally. I couldn't test it all the way through but it should work...

Comment: Great! You rock! Thank you very much :) Switzerland style :P